# Gitlab sigin in and redirect to a 422 page

Tags: gitlab, http-status-code-422

I just install a new gitlab-ce instance.
I set the property [external_url] 'https://xxxxx' a https protocol,but I did not enable the ssl.
So I visite the https://xxxx and it can sigin in.
But the browser tell me this site is insecurity.So I edit the property [external_url] to 'http://xxxx' to a http protocol.
Then I visite http://xxxx and sigin in.
But it redirect to a 422 page.

I try to sync the server time.
But it is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

422 status indicates that you didn't add form details rightly

Answer (score 0):

I fix it.
The problem is the cookies of https://xxxx make http://xxxx redirect to a 422 page.
So I visite https://xxxx again and open the devtools and delete the cookies.
Then return to http://xxxx.
It works